# Setting height of img parent breaks flex align-items and text-align

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an auctions app where the listings are displayed with an image and the text description on the right. I want the `.img` to be `max-height` and `max-width` of `90%`. `Max-width` works, but in order to get max-height to work, I have to set the height of the `.img`'s containing block (`.a_img`). Once I do that, the `align-items: center;` and `text-align: center;` declarations of .image no longer work. What is going on and how can I get around this? Thank you.

```css
.listings {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    height: 116.8px;
}

.image {
    flex: 1.2;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.text {
    flex: 2;
}

.img {
    max-height: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
}

.a_img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="listings">
    <div class="image">
        <a class="a_img" href="www.google.com">
            <img class="img" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2660/5202/products/shopify-image_0c6f7a25-f7ae-409f-a89b-df63d9c7b463_1400x.jpg?v=1586379733" alt="Product Image">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Percentage heights in CSS are tricky. Here's how they work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Answer (score 1):

you can simply replace the `max-height` to `height` on `.image` and thereafter alter everything you want to an expected output like the following

```css
.listings {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  height: 116.8px;
}

.image {
  /*flex: 1;*/
  /* altered */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  /* altered */
}

.text {
  flex: 1;
}

.img {
  max-height: 90%;
  max-width: 90%;
}

.a_img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="listings">
  <div class="image">
    <a class="a_img" href="www.google.com">
      <img class="img" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2660/5202/products/shopify-image_0c6f7a25-f7ae-409f-a89b-df63d9c7b463_1400x.jpg?v=1586379733" alt="Product Image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like if I use a wide image, align-items is still not working? I solved it somehow by making .a_image another flex container. Thank you.

Comment: what you want me to improve and upvote and accept the answer